# Count every fourth word in a file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a tsv file of words and I want to write a bash that counts how many quartets are in the file and exports the name of the file and the number of quartets to a csv file.

For example for the file fileName.tsv: I,have,this,word,cat,home,dog,day

The result would be a csv file with fileName.tsv,2.

Comment: My files looks like this : <id_DSZejorS3W_owS_iz?V!2lotR> <wikicat_Prehistoric_animal_orders>
rdfs:subClassOf <wikicat_Animal_orders>  and I want count each 4 words and print how many quartets I have.

Comment: `tsv` means tab separated, `csv` is what you give as an example. Also you could define if empty fields count and confrim if you want to print only `1` for a case with `7` "words".

Comment: Does any of the "words" (comma-delimited fields) ever contain spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of quartets, you can count the number of words, use integer division to divide by four.

First I'd use `sed 's/,/ /g'` to substitute `,` with   so that the number of words can be easily parsed.  Then I'd pipe that into `wc -w` to count the number of words.  Finally I'd use `bash` to perform integer division with `$(( x / 4 ))`.  That looks like this:

```
$ cat fileName.tsv 
I,have,this,word,cat,home,dog,day

$ sed 's/,/ /g' fileName.tsv
I have this word cat home dog day

$ sed 's/,/ /g' fileName.tsv | wc -w
8

$ echo $(( $(sed 's/,/ /g' fileName.tsv | wc -w) / 4 ))
2
```

You mentioned making a csv file with <filename,quartet>.  I assume you'd want more than one line so you can use a loop in bash to parse each file matching a pattern.

```
for filename in *.tsv; do
  quartet=$(( $(sed 's/,/ /g' $filename | wc -w) / 4 ))
  echo $filename,$quartet >> output.csv
done
```

Comment: The code worked foר one file (when I write the name of the file instead of using filename.tsv) but when I try to run the loop it says that sed can't read filename.tsv: No such file or directory

Comment: Whoops, I had a small mistake when copy+pasting the line to the loop.  Fixed.  You can see the changes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/618879/revisions)

Comment: Thank you, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$ echo "I,have,this,word,cat,home,dog,day"|gawk -F, '{printf("%d\n", NF/4)}'
2
```

Comment: Also `awk -F, '{print int(NF/4)}'`